# Managing BLOBS in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

My application using Oracle 11g as backend. We have a multiple BLOB Columns in Different tables. We are using these columns to store files such as *.Doc,*.excel,etc. First question is whether storing as BLOB supports Full-text search?

My second question is whether keeping a single table for storing all BLOB data and create a single text index that can be used to search the documents? Is it will be better than keep it in different table columns and separate full-text search indexes? If I keep all the files in a single table shall I exculde the group of rows from Full text search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can store your documents in BLOB columns and then index them with Oracle Text (see [manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/toc.htm)).

And I'm not sure if multiple BLOB columns are supported (multiple text columns are fine though, I've used it myself).

It might be more difficult to have a single text index over different tables. This could be the answer to your second question that you in fact need to merge all documents into a single table.

When using Oracle Text, it seems as if the text index is just an additional index on your table. However, the text index consists of several additional tables that Oracle creates automatically. You cannot change that.

Comment: My first question is got clarified and I have read that in oracle docs also.Thanks. But for second question, I have seen some information about the 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE'. In one of discussion it is stated that we can combine multiple text columns in different tables and create a single text index. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: I have successfully used a MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE for columns containing only text. Yet I don't think it really works for special formats since Oracle (according to the documentation) just concatenates the columns. That would destroy the integrity of formats such as Word or Excel. But a test will show for sure. The easiest route is most likely to merge all BLOB data in a single column of a single table and then index it with Oracle Text.

Comment: In case of creating a single index for the BLOB Column, How to make it useful for indexing files stored inside the table and file stored in the FileSystem (on a shared location). I will store the FileName and path in the table in different columns.